# Questions beginner request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm making a request for a certain URL, which returns the value in STING format:

```
"{\" uid \ ": 23, \" uf \ ": \" CE \ ", \" state \ ": \" Ceará \ ", \" cases \ ": 229072, \" deaths \ ": 8739, \ "suspects \": 493, \ "refuses \": 89, \ "datetime \": \ "2020-09-15T22: 34: 32.837Z \"} "
```

I'm new to using this, and I would like to get specific information, such as "states"

How do I access the values?

I tried to convert with JSON.stringify

And it returns the same value only with "/" ...

How do I read only the property
"state" of the JSON file?

I thought of body.state or something but it doesn't work.

code below:

```js
const request = require('request');
var uf = 'ce'
request(`https://covid19-brazil-api.now.sh/api/report/v1/brazil/uf/${uf}`, (error,response,body)=> {
    if(!error){
        console.log('Status ', response && response.statusCode);
        console.log(JSON.strinjsfy(body))
    }else{
        console.log(error)
    }

})

//Retorna: Status  200
"{\"uid\":23,\"uf\":\"CE\",\"state\":\"Ceará\",\"cases\":229072,\"deaths\":8739,\"suspects\":493,\"refuses\":89,\"datetime\":\"2020-09-15T22:34:32.837Z\"}"
```

Comment: `I tried to convert with JSON.stringify` looks like you're getting JSON ... so use JSON.parse to create an object

Answer (score 0):

You can parse JSON like this:

```js
const jsonData = JSON.parse(data)

jsonData.state
```

Answer (score 0):

The way API's call return a value is in JSON, this is how the data is shared, you are able to successfully get the JSON data but unable to utilize it right. Try using JSON.parse  to convert JSON data in an object with which you can play then.

**The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse